# What hash algorithm is Disqus using now for users' emails?

Tags: hash

Disqus previously used the MD5 algorithm to hash users' emails. A group of Swedes used a dictionary attack to reveal the email addresses (and in many cases identities) of hundreds of Disqus users, many of whom had made right-wing comments(which are taboo across most of the western world). Anyway, I would like to know what hash algorithm Disqus is using now to store users' emails. On their website, they said that they stopped using MD5, but they didn't say what hash algorithm they changed to. I am researching Disqus for an assignment, so that's why I want to know this.

Comment: Why not just ask them?

Answer (score 1):

The [hash was created by Gravatar, not Disqus](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/1389598-statement-in-response-to-a-report-of-%22cracking-disqus%22) and [it appears that Gravatar is still using MD5](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/hash/) to create user lookup IDs; meaning the intent of this implementation is to make it easy to create, store and lookup users, not hide who the user is.  Also appears that [Disqus still supports Gravatar](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/1255134-updating-your-disqus-settings); meaning MD5 is still the hash being used.